# How can one start transcription in Microsoft Teams for Android?

Tags: voice-recognition, microsoft-teams

How can one start transcription in Microsoft Teams for Android?

I don't see the option:

[image]

I use MS Teams on Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

It's different from turning on captions. I do have the start transcription option in the Microsoft Teams clients for Windows and MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is not yet available for mobile.

> Current limitations
>
> **Live transcription is currently available:**
>
> - For scheduled meetings.
> - When the spoken language is U.S. English.
> - On the installed desktop version of Teams.
> - For customers with the following licenses: Office 365 E1, Office 365 A1, Office 365/Microsoft 365 A3, Office 365/Microsoft 365 A5, Microsoft 365 F1, Office 365/Microsoft 365 F3, Microsoft 365 Business Basic, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, Microsoft 365 Business Premium SKUs.
>
> **The feature is not available:**
>
> - In channel meetings or Meet now meetings.
> - In GCC, GCC-High, and DoD environments.

The only option currently available is to access the transcript, if made available, after the meeting has ended.

Source: [View live transcription in a Teams meeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-live-transcription-in-a-teams-meeting-dc1a8f23-2e20-4684-885e-2152e06a4a8b#ID0EABAAA=Desktop).